# SherlockFragmentActivity EditText getText() nullpointerexception

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-edittext

I have this error `nullpointerexception`, when i do `getText().toString()` from EditTex:

```
public class SendMessActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity  {    
   private  EditText tEmail;
   private  Button sendButton;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.send_mess_layout);
   tEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editEmailTo);
   sendButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_sendmess);
   endButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           //String textEmail = tEmail.getText().toString(); //nullpointerexception
           Editable textEmail1Editable = tEmail.getText(); //nullpointerexception
           String textEmail = textEmail1Editable.toString()
           Log.d(DEBUGTAG, "SENDING START::::::::  " + textEmail);
         }
    });

}}
```

Please, tell me how to do it

**UPDATE Q**

**David**, thank you, for your surmise,the problem was really in the my tangled Layouts
I had all 4 levels of nesting LinearLayouts.
After I left the simplified scheme and only 2 levels I have, all began to work

Comment: Can you please post the layout file send_mess_layout.xml. I expect the issue lies in there.

Comment: Perhaps you are right, my layout crooked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `setContentView(your_layout.xml)` so it knows what layout to use.  Without setting the layout, all of your calls to `findViewById(...)` that try to find the views in your layout will return null.

```
public class SendMessActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity  {     
   private  EditText tEmail;
   private  Button sendButton;
 @Override 
 protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


   setContentView(your_layout.xml); //set your activity layout here.


   tEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editEmailTo);
   sendButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_sendmess);
   endButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override 
        public void onClick(View view) {
           String textEmail = tEmail.getText().toString(); //nullpointerexception
           Log.d(DEBUGTAG, "SENDING START::::::::  " + textEmail);
         } 
    }); 

}}
```

Comment: Sorry, i already have ```setContentView(R.layout.send_mess_layout);```, but I have the same error

Comment: `tEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editEmailTo);` has to be the culprit.  Step through in your debugger and see if it is null.

Comment: yes you are right, the problem was due to the fact that there were too many nested Layouts. After I simplified scheme UI, it worked Ok!

Answer (score 0):

If you have no assigned text then I would assume that the EditText retrieval of the text would be a null entry and you are attempting to make a string of that null entry.

Comment: Please, see updaate ```Editable textEmail1Editable = textEmail.getText(); //nullpointerexception```